# Correct form of gravitational time dilation comparison between frames?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, gravity, time-dilation

So, assuming the following is correct, for proper time $\tau$ and reference time $t$ with $\phi$ potential per unit mass

$$dt \approx \frac{d\tau}{\sqrt{1+\frac{2\phi}{c^2}}}$$

If you're trying to work out the dilation between two frames $A$ & $B$. Do you use the following?

$$(1) \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \frac{dt_A}{dt_B} = \frac{\sqrt{1+\frac{2\phi_B}{c^2}}}{\sqrt{1+\frac{2\phi_A}{c^2}}}$$

Using the fact $d\tau$ will be invariant. Or, use the following, which seems to follow the same reasoning as the difference in velocity between frames?

$$(2) \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \frac{dt_A}{dt_B} = \sqrt{1+\frac{2(\phi_A-\phi_B)}{c^2}}$$

Or are they equivalent? Or is it another form all together?

I've seen both quoted and I'm confused as to when to use which.

Many thanks!